# Why does Ubuntu 18.04 come with rustc 1.18?

Tags: versions, 18.04, rust

I'm aware of the fact that Ubuntu 18.04 isn't released yet and things can change. However, [all versions < 18.04 provide `rustc` 1.21](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=rustc&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) whereas 18.04 comes with 1.18 which already is quite old (recent Firefox versions needs at least 2.23 to build). Is there a reason for this downgrade? Is it worth to suggest to not do it until the release?

Comment: [Questions about the development version of Ubuntu are off-topic on this site](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic). You can [report it as a bug](https://askubuntu.com/q/5121/616451) if you'd like.

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex You're right, I forgot that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rustc 1.23` is in proposed repos for 18.04. If everything goes right (in development), 18.04 may be released with version 1.23. If not, you can get it by enabling proposed repos.

Package Details : https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/bionic/+source/rustc